# Are Allahs hands, eyes and other features considered under asma wa siffat?

Tags: quran, hadith, aqidah

After reading following books and other booklets on tawheed like.

1. Kitab at tawheed by ibn abdul wahhab.
2. The Aqeedah of tawheed by saalih al fowzaan.
3. Fundamentals of tawheed by bilal philips.
4. Creed of the muslim.

I learnt that Allahs hands and other features dont fall under catoegory of Asma was siffat. And Allahs 99 names and characteristics like smiling, rejoicing come under asma was siffat.

Again in discussion one person said Allahs hands and features like eyes, face, shin, face and fingers fall under asma wa siffat.

I asked for evidence. He suggested creed book of sk.utheymeen.

The book creed of ahlul sunnah wal jamaah by Sk.utheymeen also doesn't have Allahs hands and other features in asma was siffat.

Hence the question does Allah's face, hands, shin, fingers, foot and eyes fall under asma was siffat?

only one website is saying they are divine attributes islamqa.info/en. Without giving evidence of how they arrived. https://www.google.com/amp/s/islamqa.info/amp/en/answers/151794

Answer (score 1):

When Allah describes Himself by mentioning His Hands or Face or His Wrath or Laugh, all of this can not be understood by comparing this to His creation (humans). Ahlus-Sunnah believes in what Allah has revealed, for example that He has Hands, but how they look like and what they are is not to be interpreted or imagined because nothing is like Allah and He is independent of His creation. His description of Himself is not decreasing him in any way, but people make the mistake by trying to look behind the curtain while Allah has made it impossible to conceive that in the Dunya. And certain groups try to implement interpretation in a metaphorical sense which is contrary to Ahlus-Sunnah while there is overwhelming evidence in Qur‘an and Sunnah to dispute a philosophical or any other ideological approach trying to explain Allahs Attributes, but was effectively countered by the greats such as Shaykul Islam Ibn Taymiyyah.

Comment: I do agree with that all. But srsly sheik al Islam is Ibn Taymiyyah? XD I fell from my chair laughing.

Comment: @harmer97 what about the hadith Allah created Adam in His image.

Comment: Ibn Qutaybah said: “That Allah should have an image is no stranger than His having two hands, fingers or eyes. Rather those are readily accepted because they are mentioned in the Qur’an, but this idea (image or form) is regarded as strange because it is not mentioned in the Qur’aan. But we believe in them all, but we do not discuss how any of them are.”  Ta'wil Mukhtalif al-Hadith (p. 221)

Comment: "Rather the image of Allah is different from that of created beings. What is meant is that He is All-Hearing, All-Seeing, and He speaks when He wants, and He created Adam also able to hear and see, with a face and hands and feet. But man’s hearing is not like Allah’s hearing, his seeing is not like Allah’s seeing, his speaking is not like Allah’s speaking. Rather Allah has attributes that befit His majesty and might, and man has attributes that befit him, attributes that are finite and imperfect, whereas the attributes of Allah are perfect, with no shortcomings, infinite and without end."

Comment: Majmu’ Fatawa al-Shaykh (4/226) from Shaykh Ibn Baz

Comment: @ShaikAbdullah Sure whatever. Keep following those revolutionists of yours. End of discussion.

Comment: @SyedMohammadSannan I do not understand what kind of hatred you have and why you are describing your separation from "revolutionists"? What do you mean by that term? I do not identifiy myself to any group except in the one that the Prophet (ﷺ) described in At-Tirmidhi (2641): "[...] *and my Ummah will split into 73 groups. All of them are in the Fire except one group.*" [It was asked]: '[...] and which is it, O Messenger of Allah?' He said: "*What I am upon and my Companions.*" And this is Ahlus-Sunnah wal Jama'ah, the saved, united group in Jannah.

Comment: @harmer97 I am also from ahlus-sunnah wal Jama'ah brother, but just a thing to mention here that Ibn Taymiyyah was a sunni but wasn't from ahl-ul-sunnah. The ones that are from ahl-as-sunnah (there are many operations inside ahl as sunnah itself) are the sufis such as Imam Abu Hanifa, Sheikh Ahmad Sirhind, Abdul Qadir Jilani, Ibn Al Arabi, etc. Ibn Taymiyyah and Ibn Abdul Wahab denied many Islamic theories such as tasawwuf, sufism, etc. and were the so called "rationalist" Muslims. Ibn Taymiyyah and Abdul Wahab labelled many things unjustly as "bidah", etc. and overall denied spiritualism.